# deploy web app from local computer to remote tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, web-deployment

I have my Hello project created locally at my PC and get a WAR file after building it from Netbeans. It was tested working if I put the WAR file under the /webapps folder on my local tomcat directory. I can type localhost:8080/Hello in the browser and it shows me the message I put up in the project.

However, when I tried to copy the WAR file to the /webapps directory on remote tomcat server using WinSCP. I restarted the tomcat in putty. After that, I put up the address http://WEB-ADDRESS.EDU/Hello/ in the browser. However, it just showed me HTTP STATUS 404 ERROR: The requested resource (/Hello/) is not available. I also tried http://WEB-ADDRESS.EDU:8080/Hello/, which didn't work neither.

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out this problem and thought it would benefit others who might have the issue to mine.

I was setting my project and local tomcat as using JRE 1.7. However, the remote tomcat was using JRE 1.6, which caused this problem. After configuring the tomcat with 1.7, then the deployed webapp can work on the server.